# How to use string as code in R

Tags: r

Following works:

```
plot(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Width, data = iris)
abline(lm(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Width, data = iris))
```

But following code does not work:

```
str = "Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Width, data = iris"
plot(str)
abline(lm(str))
```

I tried deparse(substitute), as.forumla and eval but they do not work.

Comment: You could do something like `str = "Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Width"; 
plot(as.formula(str), data = iris);
abline(lm(str, iris))`. Though it is not exactly what you want

Comment: Can 'data=iris' be also included in code?

Comment: Probably can using some very nasty `parse`/`deparse`/`quote`/`...` combinations. Or using some external package, but I may be wrong here

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers. The question did interest some geniuses here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `str` from the question try this:

```
 # fun and args should each be a character string
 run <- function(fun, args) eval(parse(text = sprintf("%s(%s)", fun, args)))

 run("plot", str)
 abline(run("lm", str))
```

Or try this:

```
 `%(%` <- function(fun, args) run(deparse(substitute(fun)), args)
 plot %(% str
 abline(lm %(% str)
```

Note that this approach can handle the situation where there are commas in an argument (as opposed to argument separators) and does not make use of any external packages.

Answer (score 2):

Try to parse arguments and create them :

```
fun_str<- function(fun, str_arg){
    ## split args separted by comma
    m <- as.list(strsplit(str_arg,',')[[1]])
    args  <- lapply(m,function(x){
      ## remove any extra space 
      arg = str_trim(strsplit(x,'=')[[1]])
      if (arg[1]=="data") get(arg[2],parent.frame())
      else if (grepl('~',x))  as.formula(x)
    })
    do.call(fun,args)
}
```

Then call it :

```
fun_str("plot",str)
fun_str("lm",str)
```

Comment: This has problems if there is a comma in the argument, e.g. if `main = "Sepal.Length, Sepal.Length"` is part of the string.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another alternative. You could use a `call` object to represent the `data` argument and then evaluate it in the argument list.

```
f <- formula("Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Width")
cl <- call("=", "data", iris)
plot(f, eval(cl))
abline(lm(f, eval(cl)))
```

It looks like this alternate solution will also work with the original `str` vector.

```
str <- "Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Width, data = iris"
s <- strsplit(str, ", data = ")[[1]]
with(setNames(as.list(s), c("formula", "data")), {
    getd <- get(data, parent.frame())
    plot(f <- formula(formula), data = getd)
    abline(lm(f, data = getd))
})
```